# what is shape-id and how can I find it in a css file?

Tags: html, css

It may be trivial to web developers but what is shape-id?

As in `<hr shape-id="2">`.

I am trying to change the color of hr lines in my site and can't seem to find it anywhere in the css.

I know that id can by found by `#someId` and class by `.someClass` but how do I find shape-id?

I tried adding `hr{}` to my css but it doesn't seem to be working.

I am working in Orchard CMS btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a attribute , not ID, you need to use attribute selector to select it.

```
[shape-id="2"] {
  color: #f00;
  background-color: #f00;
  height: 5px;
}​​
```

***[Check the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/LDqnv/)***